# Asp.Net Mvc localization with embeded resx files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization, resx

Hi we are making a site in Asp.Net Mvc which is localized with embeded resx files.

On the nightly server we have the site showing in english but switching to german does not work where as locally it does.

Decompiling the dll we deployed I can see the resources are there but only in english?

should I be deploying the resx (even though they are set to Public and so have the generator ran against them) files along with the dlls?

w://

Comment: how are your german resources named and stored?

Comment: they are in Resources/strings.resx Resources/strings.de.resx etc

Answer (score 1):

> should I be deploying the resx

This will depend on where are those resources defined. If you use the ASP.NET `App_GlobalResources` folder, then you should deploy the 2 resx files: `Resources.resx` and `Resources.de-DE.resx` along with your application.

If you put resources in a separate class library or in a some custom folder in yuor ASP.NET MVC application like `Resources/Strings.resx` and `Resources/Strings.de-DE.resx` then you should deploy the generated satellite assembly in `bin\de-DE\MyClassLibrary.resources.dll` which will contain the `de-DE` resource strings whereas your `bin\MyClassLibrary.dll` will contain the default language strings.